# Optimum baseball distance from velocity

Tags: friction, velocity, drag

I am trying to come up with an equation that is able to approximate the magnitude of velocity of a baseball after it travelled a certain distance in the $x-$direction given the ball is thrown at an angle of $\theta$.

I came across the following site [here](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Scientific_Computing_Simulations_and_Modeling/Physical_Modeling_in_MATLAB_(Downey)/12%3A_Two_Dimensions/12.04%3A_Drag_Force#:%7E:text=The%20drag%20coefficient%20for%20a,baseball%20is%200.0042%20m2.) and included drag into the equation.

In the article, it discusses $\overrightarrow{F_d}=-\frac{1}{2}\rho v C_d A \hat{v} $ which we can divide by $m$ to figure out the acceleration of the drag force $\overrightarrow{a_d}=\frac{\overrightarrow{F_d}}{m}=-\frac{1}{2m}\rho v C_d A \hat{v} $ where acceleration of the ball is the following: $\overrightarrow{a}=\text{acceleration of drag}+\text{acceleration due to gravity}=-\frac{1}{2m}\rho v C_d A \hat{v} -g\hat{j}$

After doing this calculation and solving for position by integrating it and doing some tedious algebra, I was able to conclude that a baseball thrown at a 45 degree angle at 90 mph would still travel a distance well over 500 ft which is way off (it should be closer to 300 ft).

> Is there a formula that someone knows that is used to better approximate the distance a baseball is thrown given this scenario?

Comment: Do not know what is the adequate drag here, but did you try quadratric speed drag: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_(physics)

Comment: That would probably work out better because the speed is squared. Do you know if there would be a way to get acceleration as a vector from that equation though?

Comment: It is the same, just multiply by $-\hat{v}/m$. See this simulator https://dynref.engr.illinois.edu/afp.html#:~:text=Quadratic%20drag%20model%23afp%E2%80%91sq&text=This%20is%20referred%20to%20as,%E2%88%92cv2%5Ev.